# numpy.cov returning a matrix which is not positive semi-definite

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scikit-learn, covariance

I'm calculating a covariance matrix from a 2D array using np.cov, and using it to get nearest neighbors with Mahalanobis distance.

```
c = np.cov(arr)
neigh = NearestNeighbors(100,metric='mahalanobis',metric_params = {'VI':np.linalg.inv(c)})
neigh.fit(dfeatures)
```

But for some reason, I'm getting

```
/lib/python3.4/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py:131: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt
```

and the values of the distance of any query point returns *nan*.

Instead of passing *c* to *NearestNeighbors*, if I pass an identity matrix the *NearestNeighbors* works as expected. I suspected that *c* might actually not be positive semidefinite and therefore the values in the *sqrt* in Mahalanobis distance might get a negative value as input.

I checked the eigenvalue of resulting *c* and many of them turned out to be negative(and complex) but close to 0.

I'd a few questions:

- Is this totally because of the numerical errors(or am I doing something wrong)?
- If it is because of numerical errors is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Are you aware that `np.cov` expects observations in columns while sklearn usually expects them in rows? If yes, please provide more details about your data - preferable in form of a [minimal, complete, and verifyable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is in-fact because of numerical error. A workaround to correct this is to add a small number to diagonal element of covariance matrix. The larger this number the closer the distance will be to euclidean distance, so one must be careful while choosing this number.